# Find unique words in a file - Java

Tags: java

Using a msdos window I am piping in an amazon.txt file.
I am trying to use the collections framework. Keep in mind I want to keep this
as simple as possible.
What I want to do is count all the unique words in the file... with no duplicates.

This is what I have so far. Please be kind this is my first java project.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class project1 {

    // ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String  word;
        String grab;

        int count = 0;
        ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
        // Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();

        System.out.println("Java project\n");

        while (sc.hasNext()) {      
            word = sc.next();  
            a.add(word); 
            if (word.equals("---")) {
            break;
            }
        }

        Iterator<String> it = a.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            grab = it.next();

            if (grab.contains("a")) {
                System.out.println(it.next()); // Just a check to see
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("I counted abc = ");
        System.out.println(count);
        System.out.println("\nbye...");
    }
}
```

Comment: please add homework tag.

Comment: Practice for better copy-paste skills :)

Comment: Nicolai, this happens when the editor where you copy from uses tabs for indentation. Quite annoying - you have to reformat every single line...

Comment: I changed the original post - i want to count all the original words.. no duplicates..

Comment: The file has alot of "a" letters in it(like: and or paragraph). however, i am trying to find just a by itself, how can i do that without counting all the letter a thats in other words.?
i tried if(grab.contains("a"))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your version, the wordlist `a` will contain all words but duplicates aswell. You can either

(a) check for every new word, if it is already included in the list (`List#contains` is the method you should call), or, the recommended solution

(b) replace `ArrayList<String>` with `TreeSet<String>`. This will eliminate duplicates automatically and store the words in alphabetical order

**Edit**

If you want to count the unique words, then do the same as above and the desired result is the collections size. So if you entered the sequence "a a b c ---", the result would be 3, as there are three unique words (a, b and c).

Comment: ok, i did what you said and used TreeSet.. and just did a count and Got 8 unique words thanks..

Comment: Just remember that `"Word"` and `"word"` are two different words as far as the TreeSet is concerned. So if you want it to be case-insensitive, you would have to do a `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` before adding the `String` to the TreeSet

Comment: Does TreeSet count integers? I dont want to count them!

Comment: The TreeSet will contain each unique thing that you put into it.  If you don't want to count integers, or punctuation, or whatever, don't put them into the set.

Comment: The file has alot of "a" letters in it(like: and or paragraph). however, i am trying to find just a by itself, how can i do that without counting all the letter a thats in other words.?
i tried if(grab.contains("a"))

Answer (score 3):

Instead of ArrayList<String>, use HashSet<String> (not sorted) or TreeSet<String> (sorted) if you don't need a count of how often each word occurs, Hashtable<String,Integer> (not sorted) or TreeMap<String,Integer> (sorted) if you do.

If there are words you don't want, place those in a HashSet<String> and check that this doesn't contain the word your Scanner found before placing into your collection. If you only want dictionary words, put your dictionary in a HashSet<String> and check that it contains the word your Scanner found before placing into your collection.

Comment: if i placed it into the hashset how would i use my scanner to check for those words?

Comment: You use your scanner to pick up a sequence of characters first. Then you convert that sequence of characters to all lower case (assuming all words in your HashSet are lower case), then whether that word exists in your HashSet.